# Microsoft Identity does not work in docker desktop

Tags: asp.net, docker, azure-active-directory, docker-desktop, microsoft-identity-web

Problem : Microsoft Identity does not work in docker desktop

I am able to reproduce it in a sample demo project.
I created a simple ASP.Net Web API which uses Microsoft Identity for Auth.

After launching API from Visual Studio I can call it from API tester and Auth work all good.

But when I create a docker container of it and run it in Docker Desktop then the problem comes.

Code

> Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(builder.Configuration);

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
   app.UseSwagger();
   app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

> WeatherForecast.cs

```
namespace TestingMicrosoftIdentity
{
   public class WeatherForecast
   {
      public DateTime Date { get; set; }

      public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

      public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);

      public string? Summary { get; set; }
   }
}
```

> Dockerfile

```
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TestingMicrosoftIdentity.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./TestingMicrosoftIdentity.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "TestingMicrosoftIdentity.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TestingMicrosoftIdentity.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestingMicrosoftIdentity.dll", "--urls", "http://*:8080"]
```

> appsettings.json

```
{
   "Logging": {
      "LogLevel": {
         "Default": "Information",
         "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
      }
   },
   "AzureAd": {
      "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
      "TenantId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "ClientId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
   },
   "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

> WeatherForecastController.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace TestingMicrosoftIdentity.Controllers
{
   [ApiController]
   [Authorize]
   [Route("[controller]")]
   public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
   {
      private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
      {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

      private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

      public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
      {
         _logger = logger;
      }

      [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
      public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
      {
         return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
         {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
         })
         .ToArray();
      }
   }
}
```

> launchSettings.json

```
{
   "profiles": {
      "TestingMicrosoftIdentity": {
         "commandName": "Project",
         "launchBrowser": true,
         "launchUrl": "swagger",
         "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
         },
         "dotnetRunMessages": true,
         "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:8080"
      }
   }
}
```

> CS Proj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx</UserSecretsId>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <DockerfileContext>.</DockerfileContext>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.19.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="8.0.0" />

      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="4.59.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal" Version="4.56.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.17.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" Version="7.3.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="7.3.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Problem is while Auth it fails and shows following,

> Docker Desktop Error Log

```
PS C:\Users\aanantj\DI> docker run -p 8080:8080 testingmicrosoftidentity:latest
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
      Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured. Key {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://[::]:8080
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /app/
fail: Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter[0]
      Microsoft.IdentityModel Version: 7.3.1.0. Date 04/01/2024 16:47:24. PII logging is OFF. See https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII for details.
      Message: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'., InnerException: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException.
fail: Microsoft.IdentityModel.LoggingExtensions.IdentityLoggerAdapter[0]
      Message: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'. Will retry at '04/01/2024 16:47:24 +00:00'. Exception: 'System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
       ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
       ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.SendAsyncAndRetryOnNetworkError(HttpClient httpClient, Uri uri)
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)'., InnerException: System.IO.IOException.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[3]
      Exception occurred while processing message.
      System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'. Will retry at '04/01/2024 16:47:24 +00:00'. Exception: 'System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
       ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
       ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.SendAsyncAndRetryOnNetworkError(HttpClient httpClient, Uri uri)
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)'.
       ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
       ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
       ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.SendAsyncAndRetryOnNetworkError(HttpClient httpClient, Uri uri)
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "XXXXXXXXXXXXX", Request id "XXXXXXXXXXXXX:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
      System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'. Will retry at '04/01/2024 16:47:24 +00:00'. Exception: 'System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
       ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
       ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.SendAsyncAndRetryOnNetworkError(HttpClient httpClient, Uri uri)
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)'.
       ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
       ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
       ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.SendAsyncAndRetryOnNetworkError(HttpClient httpClient, Uri uri)
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

I searched many posts on internet but no one has reported similar issue.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.